# Who figured out the numerical value of Coulomb's constant, when did this happen, and how?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, history, coulombs-law

Coulomb demonstrated the form of the electric force law, but I'm pretty sure he did not determine the numerical value of the constant. If so, who determined that k=9x10^9 (or whatever it is in cgs or other units used back then, I don't care about the units), when, and how?

Thanks

Comment: [Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) figured out that you can just set it to 1. Unfortunately, whoever designed SI ignored that excellent advice.

Comment: This is more a question for history of science and mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: Would this question fit better at [hsm.se]? We can migrate it if you like.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_constant has some info. There was no need to measure it until fairly recently.

Comment: Yes, if it's better in the History of Sci and Math, please migrate it. Thank you

Comment: To Ghoster, sure, the constant is one if you use esu/franklin, but then how to figure out what that unit is? To Jon, seems like there must have been some need to be able to predict the numerical value of, say, electric field strength, before recently? Gauss' law uses epsilon0 which is equivalent to knowing the Coulomb constant, obviously.